# SSL approach for private software

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

What is the proper way of using SSL certificates for private applications? By private I mean that I am the only user, and software is running on my computers.

I want to have a encrypted communication between two of my programs. I want to send passwords between them, so I need to be sure that remote program is not fake/hacked.

As far as I understand I don't need to get paid SSL certificate from the CA, if there is no third party involved.

Is the following correct?

1. Server has a private key and self-signed SSL certificate.
2. Client has a copy of server's self-signed certificate (it needs to be well protected).
3. During the handshake server sends the certificate to client.
4. client checks if the certificates are the same.
5. client can start encrypted transmission.

Is there other way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww This question regards software design.

Comment: Yeah, and you're a developer, too. Just because you are a developer does not make the question on-topic. If you need to learn how SSL/TLS works, then there are other sites for that. It will save you from all the bad answers you get on Stack Overflow. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

> Server has a private key and self-signed SSL certificate.

Yes

> Client has a copy of server's self-signed certificate (it needs to be well protected).

The client has either a copy of the certificate or the certificates public key or the fingerprint of these. Since the certificate is public these information do not need to be protected. Only the private key of the server (residing only in the server side) needs to be protected because using this key one could prove ownership of the certificate.

> During the handshake server sends the certificate to client.

Yes.

> client checks if the certificates are the same.

Kind of. It might check the certificate or the public key or the fingerprints.

> client can start encrypted transmission.

Yes.

I would recommend that you read the OWASP article about [certificate and public key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). It also contains sample code for various environments.

Comment: I think I need to protect the certificate/public-key/fingerprint on the client side, in case if someone would try to substitute it ?

Comment: SSL is used to protect the transport between client and server. It does not help if somebody is able to tamper with the client directly, no matter if it is replacing the fingerprints or debugging the client. Since the client itself contains the plain data before encryption tampering with the client can show the attacker the plain data and no TLS will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> > Client has a copy of server's self-signed certificate (it needs to be well protected).

Clients do not have copy of the server certificate. They get it in SSL handshake

> > client checks if the certificates are the same.

NO! Clients will have the public certificate of the Certificate Authorities who would have signed the server certificate. They will validate the server cert with the CA cert including things like certificate expiry, CRLs. Not compare for 'sameness'

In your case you are using the self-signed certificates. The clients should be made to ignore the self signed certificate and proceed with SSL handshake.

I would recommend you read through SSL handshake sequence again.

Comment: "The clients should be made to ignore the self signed certificate and proceed with SSL handshake." - in which case you could use any other self-signed certificate and thus make a man-in-the-middle attack easy.

Comment: *"Clients do not have copy of the server certificate. They get it in SSL handshake"* - that's only in the general case. In this case, the apps have *a priori* knowledge, so they can leverage that knowledge (and not do dumb things like browsers). See, for example, [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, very true. OP was intending for 'one-use','one-computer'.  Had mentioned that to get things going in his/her experiment.

Comment: In my case there is only one client. Do I need certificate signed by CA?

Comment: You don't need a CA signed certificate in your case. CA are only used because you usually can not distribute every certificate to each client in a secure way and thus you simplify the thing by considering everything as trusted which is signed by a trusted CA and fits the hostname.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, so you think that the approach is proper?

Comment: @jww. Thanks. I am learning something new. I must be missing some key information regarding this. As some one beginning to know Certificate Pinning, does the process not open up for anybody to hijack the session and present themselves as actual server? man-in-the-middle-attack?